# Using recursive function to find all childrens children IDS of a certain parent ID

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression, recursive-query, mysql-8.0

I have a table named `concept_has_parent_concepts` with `concept_ids` and their `parent_ids`, the `concept_ids` are actually the `child_ids` pointing to their parent.

I want to find all the children of a parent, but the children can also have children and so on.

So the main focus is to find all the children, but also their children of a certain parent with id = `300264091`.
I want to achieve this with MySQL 8 recursive function, and I came up with this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE runner (concept_id, parent_id) AS (
    SELECT concept_id AS child_id FROM concept_has_parent_concepts WHERE parent_id = 300264091
    UNION ALL
    SELECT concept_id, parent_id FROM runner WHERE concept_id = child_id
)
SELECT concept_id, parent_id FROM runner
```

But it doesn't work, it gives an error `can't find child_id` (SQL Fout (1054): Unknown column 'concept_id' in 'field list'). I'm new to the recursive function, and I'm confused. What approach should I follow to find all the childrens(children) of a parent?

### Sample data

Some sample data with more simple ID's, where parentid with NULL conceptid is already top parent:

| concept_id | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | NULL |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 8 | 7 |
| 9 | 8 |
| 10 | 9 |

```
INSERT INTO concept_has_parent_concepts (concept_id,parent_id) VALUES ('1',NULL);
INSERT INTO concept_has_parent_concepts (concept_id,parent_id) VALUES ('2',NULL);
INSERT INTO concept_has_parent_concepts (concept_id,parent_id) VALUES ('3','1');
INSERT INTO concept_has_parent_concepts (concept_id,parent_id) VALUES ('4','1');
INSERT INTO concept_has_parent_concepts (concept_id,parent_id) VALUES ('5','2');
INSERT INTO concept_has_parent_concepts (concept_id,parent_id) VALUES ('6','2');
INSERT INTO concept_has_parent_concepts (concept_id,parent_id) VALUES ('7','3');
INSERT INTO concept_has_parent_concepts (concept_id,parent_id) VALUES ('8','7');
INSERT INTO concept_has_parent_concepts (concept_id,parent_id) VALUES ('9','8');
INSERT INTO concept_has_parent_concepts (concept_id,parent_id) VALUES ('10','9');
```

### Expected result

Expected result with finding all childrens children of `conceptid = 1`, is finding concepts `3,4,7,8,9 and 10`.
For finding all childrens-children of `conceptid = 2` I expect finding `concepts 5, 6`.

Comment: Can you update your post with sample input data and expected output?

Comment: please show the exact entire error message

Comment: why do you have conceptid/parentid one place and concept_id/parent_id elsewhere?

Comment: [Hierarchical data traversal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-hierarchy-traversal)

Comment: The error is most likely related to the `UNION ALL`, which is applied on a different amount of fields. @ysth

Answer (score 2):

A couple of problems:

- In any UNION query (not only CTEs), all queries must have the same columns. In the case of a CTE, the queries must have the columns as those you define after the CTE name.
- The columns you define after the name of the CTE are the columns of the CTE. Any `<column> AS <alias>` you define in the CTE body are ignored. You define the columns of the CTE as `(concept_id, parent_id)`, so those are the only names you can reference.
- The latter query inside a recursive CTE is typically a JOIN between the CTE and the base table.

Here's what I tested:

```
WITH RECURSIVE runner (concept_id, parent_id) AS (
    SELECT concept_id, parent_id FROM concept_has_parent_concepts 
    WHERE concept_id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.concept_id, c.parent_id FROM runner AS r 
    JOIN concept_has_parent_concepts AS c ON r.concept_id = c.parent_id
)
SELECT concept_id, parent_id FROM runner;
```

Output:

```
+------------+-----------+
| concept_id | parent_id |
+------------+-----------+
|          1 |      NULL |
|          3 |         1 |
|          4 |         1 |
|          7 |         3 |
|          8 |         7 |
|          9 |         8 |
|         10 |         9 |
+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: I tested the query and it works on my actual dataset! It's good to be carefull with column AS alias in the body base step, I understand, to avoid confussion. So runner or r is a reference to the CTE, and c is the base model.